# A question on complex valued function.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f$ be a function which has power series representation around open nhd of $z_0$. If $f^{(n)}(z_0) \rightarrow 0$, what can we say about the function. Only polynomials will satisfy the condition? What if we assume extra such that $\sum f^{(n)}(z_0)$ converges. I could not find any explcit function other than polynomials. Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(z) = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2} z)$. Then $f^{(n)}(z) = \left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^n \exp(\tfrac{1}{2} z)$, hence $f^{(n)}(0) = \left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$, which is summable.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(z) = 17^{-1}(z-z_0) + (2!)^{-1}17^{-2}(z-z_0)^{2} + (3!)^{-1}17^{-3}(z-z_0)^3 + \cdots .$

Then $f^{(n)}(z) = 17^{-n}$ and so this non-polynomial has a series converging.

When you have problems with power series, you can just choose the coefficients to be whatever you want. So just make the coefficients have a convergent series.

Comment: Well, what you want, *provided* that $\left\{\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a bounded sequence.